# Reducing duplication in gradle scripts

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 tasks i my build.gradle script in my android project:

```
task jacocoFooTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn:'testFooDebugUnitTest') {

    def mainSrc = [
            "$project.projectDir/src/main/java",
            flavorSrcDir
    ]

    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTreeJava, debugTreeKotlin])

    executionData.from = executionDataFile
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

task jacocoBarTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn:'testBarDebugUnitTest') {

    def mainSrc = [
            "$project.projectDir/src/main/java",
            flavorSrcDir
    ]

    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTreeJava, debugTreeKotlin])

    executionData.from = executionDataFile
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

This works fine but the issue is the amount of duplication in the tasks. How can I remove this duplication?

EDIT: To be clear, the lines in both methods from `sourceDirectories.from` until the end of the method are identical.

I tried to separate it out into its own method but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you explain how your tasks differ at all? Why do you even have two (or more) tasks?

Comment: @LukasKörfer I've added some more info on what i want to do.